# How to modify content padding in sap.f.DynamicPage

Tags: sapui5

I would like to know if anyone faces this issue of awkward padding between the table and header of `sap.f.DynamicPage`:

[image: Awkward padding in Dynamic Paage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing "incorrect" about the padding between the header and the content. It's the intended design which can be seen [in the source code](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/4516544dd3cc37ad391385354fda01c778593c4b/src/sap.f/src/sap/f/themes/base/DynamicPage.less#L44-L48):

> ```CSS
> .sapFDynamicPageContent/*, ...*/ {
>   //...
>   padding: 2rem 3rem 0 3rem;
> }
> ```

## Don't

This shouldn't be changed if you're following Fiori design guidelines or if the app is supposed to be running on FLP. Please, avoid using custom CSS to remove the padding as [mentioned in the documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/723f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796):

> SAP Fiori launchpad apps should **not** override styles.

[image]

## Do (as of [v1.56](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/b00f91037a8df0bd73a2c767f096f81e2f08e6a8/src/sap.f/test/sap/f/relnotes/changes-1.56.json#L11-L16))

What we can and should, however, is to align the table with the header content by removing the side padding shown below:

[image]

This can be achieved by adding the predefined CSS class `sapFDynamicPageAlignContent` to the table with the `width: auto`. E.g. in XMLView:

```xml
<Table class="sapFDynamicPageAlignContent" width="auto">
```

> The SAP Fiori Design guidelines require that the `DynamicPageHeader`'s content and the `DynamicPage`'s content are aligned vertically. When using [sap.ui.layout.form.Form](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.Form), [sap.m.Panel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Panel), [sap.m.Table](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table) and [sap.m.List](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.List) in the content area of `DynamicPage`, you need to adjust their left text offset to achieve the vertical alignment. To do this, apply the `sapFDynamicPageAlignContent` CSS class to them and set their `width` property to `auto`. [[src]](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.f.DynamicPage/methods/getContent)

Here is an example: https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.f.sample.DynamicPageFreeStyle/preview

---

## Predefined Padding CSS Classes (as of [v1.58](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/29e2b7470fc918b3e4dd3993e26cfeb7f3520eab))

Apart from the above mentioned guidelines, `sap.f.DynamicPage` now supports the following [padding classes](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/c71f6df62dae47ca8284310a6f5fc80a):

- `sapUiNoContentPadding`
- `sapUiContentPadding`
- `sapUiResponsiveContentPadding`

E.g.: Applying this completely removes the surrounding padding:

```xml
<f:DynamicPage class="sapUiNoContentPadding">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's by design:

- [Dynamic Page | SAP Fiori Design Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/dynamic-page-layout/)
- [SAPUI5 SDK - Samples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.50.10/#/sample/sap.f.sample.DynamicPageFreeStyle/preview) (1.50.10)

actually it's the padding of the content.

With custom CSS you can decrease padding:

```
.sapFDynamicPageContent {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```